# Launch Beyond Compare(Win) for Mercurial Merge(Linux) using XServer

Tags: mercurial, x11, putty, xserver, beyondcompare

I've beyondcompare licence for my windows machine and I can't use that licence for linux installation. I work on linux server via putty from my windows system.

I could launch linux visual merge tools like meld using X server. But I'm looking for a way to use X server/X11 to launch beyondcompare from my putty session. In short, I want to launch a windows application itself from the linux env over putty.

My last choice would be to pull changes to my windows machine and do a merge on windows; push it back. But it would be nice if I could launch beyondcompare from linux.

Any Ideas?

Comment: In future, please **delete** the original question, when re-posting to another site (http://superuser.com/questions/974777/launch-beyond-comparewin-for-mercurial-mergelinux-using-xserver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to launch a diff/merge in the Windows version of Beyond Compare from a Linux system via SSH. There are three possible workarounds:

1. Upgrade your license to a multi-platform license and use the Linux
   version of Beyond Compare.
2. Run the Windows version of Beyond Compare on your Windows machine and access the files on the Linux machine using the SFTP support built into Beyond Compare Pro.
3. Install Mercurial on your Windows machine, then check out files and
   diff/merge from there. See the [Using Beyond Compare With Version
   Control Systems](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#mercurial) article to configure BC as the
   diff and merge tool for Mercurial on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I would go with option 2. Thanks.